# Need identification of yellow flowering plant

Tags: identification

The plant below is living in Zone 8-9, it started blooming at the beginning of July and it's 4 - 5 feet tall.  There is some foliage throughout the winter.
It's right under a Japanese maple and I'd like to move it so I'd also appreciate information about its transplantability and root system.

Thanks.
[image: leaves and flowers]

[image: flower closeup]

[image: bud]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Inula magnifica, an herbaceous perennial plant which may reach up to 2m tall
https://www.plant-world-seeds.com/store/view_seed_item/4691.

It can be dug up and divided, or simply moved, but this is best done in spring or, better, autumn/fall.

Comment: Could also be Telekia speciosa, formerly Inula speciosa, Bupthalmum speciosum, and five other names. Not sure if it's the same plant you mentioned, Bamboo. I grew it as B. speciosum 20 years ago, then saw it was in Inula and now it's apparently the only species in Telekia. Whew, those taxonomists can drive you crazy...

Comment: @Jurp - you're right - Claire Austin's site, which sells Telekia, mentions that it is 'not unlike' Inula magnifica... Telekia sometimes has a faint fragrance to the flowers, so if the OP notices that, its more likely Telekia, but the 'crumpled' petals in the image are certainly common on Inula...